# Failure to find MyClass.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

I have a project, which looks like this:

Structure:

```
MyProject
--- MyProject.pro
--- .qmake.conf
--- src
    --- src.pro
    --- tmp
        --- MyClass.cpp
        --- MyClass.h
```

MyProject.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = src
```

.qmake.conf

```
TOP_DIR=$$PWD
```

src.pro

```
...

INCLUDEPATH += "$$TOP_DIR/src/tmp/"

SOURCES += MyClass.cpp

HEADERS += MyClass.h

...
```

Now If I try to run qmake I'm getting warning `Failure to find MyClass.cpp`. Is there another way I can tell qmake where should he look for *.cpp/h files?

I am using Qt 5.7 (which means that DEPENDPATH won't work).

Answer (score 1):

Include paths (`INCLUDEPATH`) are only used for include statements inside the cpp/header file. Like those:

```
#include <someHeader>
```

For the project file you have to specify the relative path.

```
SOURCES += tmp/MyClass.cpp
```

Comment: I'm aware of that option, but is there any other way? What if I, for example, create another folder (at same level as `src`) and want to include a lot of files from `src`, do I realy have to manually edit all paths instead of just one?

Comment: @carobnodrvo I cannot test it right now but if you want **all** the cpp files in the directory checkout `find` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false It also can run recursively into subdirectories.